# Can I return an arbitrary value for a particular type in a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to define a generic method that returns 42 if the provided argument is an int, otherwise returns the argument unchanged.

The naive implementation does not compile:

```
// Compilation fails with: "Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `T'"
public static T Id42<T>(T x) {
    if(x is int) {
        return 42;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Casting to object first does work, but fails with a runtime error if the types do not match:

```
// If I replace 42 with a string it compiles successfully and crashes at runtime
public static T Id42<T>(T x) {
    if(x is int) {
        return (T)(Object)42;
    }
    return x;
}
```

It seems that my best option is to return `Object` instead of `T`.

Ideally, I am looking for a way to tell the compiler "look, the value I am returning has the same type that I've just checked". Is this possible?

Comment: What error do you get? Runs for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VuYIs

Comment: "If I replace 42 with a string it compiles successfully and crashes at runtime"

Do you mean that you check `if (x is int)` but then go on to `return (T)(object)"42";` (a string)? Because that's entirely expected, and contradicts what you've said about returning the _same_ type that you've just checked.

Comment: Isn't it a lot easier to just make a specific overload for these types then? The types that the calling functions put into it are normally known at compile time anyway, no?

Comment: @shambulator Yes, my question is not about how to make this code run. It's about how to make it as safe as possible. I'm just asking for learning.

Comment: @Nyerguds Yes, it looks more sensible indeed. Still, I would like to explore what the different possibilities are.

Comment: A safer alternate check is `typeof(T) == typeof(Int32)`, btw. It gets around null cases if T is explicitly provided with the call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to protect against. Checking whether `T` is `int`, then trying to cast anything other than an `int` to `T` is always going to blow up.

@Nyerguds suggestion to use separate overloads is arguably safer, as then you can do away with the inherently riskier downcasting.

Comment: @Nyerguds Safer how? `is` doesn't throw if its left operand is null, and `x is int` will return `false` if it is null.

Comment: @shambulator Well, safer as in, more reliable. If the internals are more complex than just this type check and return, it'll still use correct internal types if the given type is <Int32?> and the given value is null. Because null will not pass the `(x is int?)` check; in fact I think `is` defaults to false on null.

Comment: @shambulator Imagine instead of 42 you have a more complex expression, for ex. a mathematical expression that can potentially result in a float... That's the kind of things I want to protect against. TBH I'm quite new to C#, so I may be talking nonsense.

Comment: @lortabac then you should either cast/convert it correctly, or check for float. It's really not that complicated. Automatically valid casts don't automatically pass the `is` check, since `is` checks on a specific type.

Comment: In a statically typed language, you'll know at compile time whether your result is going to be a float or not, and returning a float cast to `T` inside a conditional which has established that `T` is `int` (granted, that's not _exactly_ what your current conditional actually tests) will throw. ETA: can you provide a description of the problem this is trying to solve? Am still not clear on what the goal is, and there might be a better way to approach it.

Comment: @shambulator I see. It makes sense.

Comment: @shambulator My goal is to learn how generics work in different languages. What I am trying to do here is possible in languages with different type systems (for ex. in Haskell you would use a GADT to "prove" type equality). I want to see what the possibilities are in a more mainstream language. From what I understand, the answer seems to be that it's not possible this way, but the same result can probably be achieved through overloading.